# C++ ODBC SQL - Insert into table not working

Tags: c++, sql-server, odbc

I have been trying to insert a row into my SQL table, i get no syntax error but unfortunately when i check my table in the SQL Server Management Studio, no new entry is added. When debugging, the retCode becomes less than zero starting from the SQLConnect() function.

```
int main()
{
    SQLHANDLE SQLEnvHandle = NULL;
    SQLHANDLE SQLConnectionHandle = NULL;
    SQLHANDLE SQLStatementHandle = NULL;
    SQLRETURN retCode = 0;

    // Insert Query
    char SQLQuery[] = "insert into crm.dbo.company_name values (22,'01 electronics','@01electronics.net');";
    // SQL Server Identifier
    char SQLServer[] = "DRIVER={SQL Server}; SERVER=localhost, 8000; DATABASE=xxxx; UID=xxxx_xxxx; PWD=xxxx;";

    do
    {
        // Allocate environment
        retCode = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &SQLEnvHandle);

        // Set ODBC Version
        retCode = SQLSetEnvAttr(SQLEnvHandle, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION,(SQLPOINTER*)SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0);

        // Allocate Connection
        retCode = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, SQLEnvHandle, &SQLConnectionHandle);

        // Set Login Timeout
        retCode = SQLSetConnectAttr(SQLConnectionHandle, SQL_LOGIN_TIMEOUT, (SQLPOINTER)5, 0);

        // Set Auto Commit
        retCode = SQLSetConnectAttr(SQLConnectionHandle, SQL_ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT, (SQLPOINTER)TRUE, 0);

        // Connect to DSN
        retCode = SQLConnect(SQLConnectionHandle, (SQLCHAR*) SQLServer, SQL_NTS, (SQLCHAR*)NULL, 0, NULL, 0);

        // Allocate Statement Handle
        retCode = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, SQLConnectionHandle, &SQLStatementHandle);

        // Prepare Statement
        retCode = SQLPrepare(SQLStatementHandle, (SQLCHAR*)SQLQuery, SQL_NTS);

        // Execute Statement    
        if (SQLExecute(SQLStatementHandle) == SQL_SUCCESS || SQLExecute(SQLStatementHandle) == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO)
            cout << "SUCCESS";
        else
            cout << "FAILURE";
    } while (FALSE);

    // Frees the resources and disconnects
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, SQLStatementHandle);
    SQLDisconnect(SQLConnectionHandle);
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, SQLConnectionHandle);
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQLEnvHandle);

    getchar();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When debugging, the retCode becomes less than zero starting from the SQLConnect() function.

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqlconnect-function?view=sql-server-2017):

> When SQLConnect returns SQL_ERROR or SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO, an
>   associated SQLSTATE value can be obtained by calling SQLGetDiagRec
>   with a HandleType of SQL_HANDLE_DBC and a Handle of ConnectionHandle

Comment: Solved, the problem was the write and edit authorities to the database were disabled.